# Jquery Airport plugin effect on mouseover on anchor tag

Tags: jquery

I am using [Jquery Aiport Plugin](http://unwrongest.com/projects/airport/)

it takes array of text element and run it one by one, how can to show the effect on mouseover

I have a menu

- Home Page
- About us
- Services
- Road Map

I am trying to show the effect of airport plugin when mouse is over

please help, new to jquery.

Regards
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(el).hover(function(){
    $(this).airport({
        // settings
    });
})
```

Comment: hi adam, thanks for reply. its working, but not stoping, how to stop it once's its started. ;o) just want to make it run once's when mouse is over.

Comment: Looking at the plugin source, there are no options or stop method, so you'd need to edit the plugin. That's probably another question altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You need to continue the author work to include that

I'm not that good at jQuery Plugins, so, my work is half-way

example in [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ufulu4/edit)

over the Hello World and you will see that the plugin starts, if you mouse out, it will pause...

problem is the "continue" part, you need to put the variables into `jQuery.data` for example so it can continue, instead of start all over again...

hope it helps somehow.